# Center to user location google maps initializer error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set a center loading point whenever user enters the app. I am getting the errow with initializer. Not sure how to fix this.
`The instance member 'StartingLocation' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

```dart
class _GmapState extends State<Gmap>  {

  Location location = new Location();
  GoogleMapController? mapController;
  late Future<Map> futureAdventures;
  var StartingLocation;

  var _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target:
  LatLng(StartingLocation.latitude, StartingLocation.longitude),
      zoom: 15);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var pos = location.getLocation();
    StartingLocation = pos;
  }
```

Tried this as well

```dart
  var pos;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      pos = _location.getLocation();
      pos = _StartingLocation;

      _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target:
      LatLng(_StartingLocation.latitude, _StartingLocation.longitude),
          zoom: 15);
    });
```

Comment: initial `_initialCameraPosition` inside your `initState` after you initialized `StartingLocation`

Comment: @reza I've tried it. https://i.imgur.com/qgLhkdo.png Why does it say pos is unused? Also getting `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<LocationData>'`